# count number of records in db with id of another table id?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a small app and I am trying to figure out, what code to write and doing research I just can't get it right.

My application has "bins", they are tabs and I have a bins table which has :id, :label_name, etc...  each bin will has a post. DB has a table posts with :id, :post_name, and I've created :bin_id. What I'm currently trying to achieve, in my design... each bin shows how many posts it has on the homepage in the sidebar (example: News Bin --- 0, Sports Bin ---- 10, Art Bin --- 12 and so on..)

Here's what I've got on the homepage for the bins structure;

```
<% @bins_list.each do |bin| %>
    <div class="label %> active<% end %>"><span class="name">
</span>
<% else %><span class="num"><%= @bins.size %></span><% end %></div>
<% end %>
```

The "class="num" line with @bin.posts.size should show the number of posts that are assigned to that bin id by going through the post table and locating all posts that :bin_id column matches to the bin id in the code above.

So each bin has its ID and is saved in DB... a user will be able to assign the post to that Bin ID and the post will save the bin id in the Post table DB under :bin_id column.

I've done the;
    class Bin < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :posts
    end

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :bin
end
```

with that I've tried in the view code above do;

```
<span class="num"><%= @bin.posts.size %></span>
```

also tried;

```
<span class="num"><%= @posts.where(:bin_id == :bin).size %></span>
```

also tried;

```
<span class="num"><%= @posts.size %></span>

class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @posts = Post.find(params[:bin_id])
    end
end
```

However that doesn't work, in terminal, I get that "posts" wasn't defined for Class #blah blah... I thought doing "has_many" and "belongs_to" in models should relate? I think also 'm a little confused how to find Bins ID and connect that and search through the Post to see if the Bins ID matches, then count all "true" posts that match that id and show count.

Any help how I can modify my code and structure it to get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: 
    <%= bin.posts.size %>

Comment: Figured out while waiting; <%= Post.where(:bin_id => bin.id).count %> but yours is much cleaner and easier to read. Geez, the amount of time I spent trying to figure this out, only to come to a short simple conclusion. Not sure why bin.posts.size didn't work before when I tried in my test. Maybe I used bins.posts.size or some small error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: that would explain the issue. :) I was starting to think my rails config was wrong for bins and post models not relating. Thanks again!